# iis web garden round robin does not work

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-garden

I have set the maximum worker processes to **2**, but see in the logs that most of the request go to same machine.

here is an example of a set of concurrent requests with the corresponding process id:

```
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 101352
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 101352
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 101352
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 101352
Even I don't know all the answers. - 101352
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
Even I don't know all the answers. - 95776
```

As you can see the web garden being a round robin is a lie.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a full view from what you show here.
You also need to connect (and show/view) the ip or the cookie of the user with each request, and also to check if the calls are one per time, or more at the same moment.

Because if you have only one call each hour for example, there no need to call the second worked process, the first one do the job just fine.

The point of more worker process, have to do with smoother response in case of multiple request at the same moment on the same resources.